# Reverse proxy for dynamic URL in apache2 server

Tags: proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

I want to do reverse proxy for dynamic URLs. Below is my case

```
abc.xyz.com/p1/#/p2?data=value

to 

xyz.com/p1/#/p2?data=value
```

I have achieved reverse proxy for static path using `<Location ''>` but not able to figure out how to do it for dynamic URLS

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, it doesn't matter what kind of URLs you have.
Could you send your Apache2 vHost Configuration, so I can analyse this further.

My approach would be

```
[...]

ServerName xyz.local

ProxyPass /p1/ http://abc.xyz.local/p1/
ProxyPassReverse /p1/ http://abc.xyz.local/p1/

[...]
```

We probably would need more infos. Is the /p1/ Path "dynamic"?

I don't think that I could help you with this. But I'll do my best, if you provide more information :)